# Efficient approach or algorithm to search all rectangle that cover a point on Cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, coordinates

I have a set of data which contains a list of array. Each array contains 4 value of coordinates which forms a rectangle.

i.e. the start and end point(Xs, Xe) on X-axis; and the start and end point(Ys, Ye) on y-axis.

```
 Xs|Xe|Ys|Ye
--------------
[[10,15,5,8],
 [9,12,5,8],
 [1,20,1,20]]
```

, for example.

And now I had a point(x,y).

To get all the rectangles that will cover the point, I simply loop through all array and compare one by one.

```python
related_rectangles = []
for rectangle in dataset:
    if x > rectangle[0] and x < rectangle[1] and y > rectangle[2] and y < rectangle[3]:
        related_rectangles.append(rectangle)
```

The complexity should be O(n).

The question is, is there any algorithm or data structure that could reduce the complexity of searching? Especially for the case that all rectangles are squares.

Thanks.

Comment: O(n) should be the minimum complexity you can get because you must loop through every rectangle anyway.

Comment: @TYeung only if the list of rectangles is different for every point, otherwise you could obviously loop over the rectangles once and divide/sort them in one or another way such that further checks are done against less number of rectangles, generally speaking.

Comment: @n0p Yes, if there are multiple queries for the same list of rectangles then a better algorithm should be possible, but I can't think of a way now.

Comment: A quadtree would seem appropriate

Comment: There is only a more efficient algorithm if there are many points to check, and the best answer depends on: whether you get all the points at once or must answer point queries one at a time; and whether the list of rectangles is the same for every point.

Comment: @MattTimmermans In my case, the rectangles list is a list with some new rectangles insert and some got deleted from time to time. Maybe there are tree support this to sort and store the rectangles?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Btw, i am interested the efficient algorithm when I could get all points before query, is that sorting the points with something like the k-dtree before query?